# Adding literal values to a QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, sqlite

I'm trying to assign rank to teams based on points earned over a number of games. Team with more points are ranked higher, and if teams have an equal number of points, the team with the least games played is ranked higher. Teams can have equal rank.

Because Django (nor SQLite) support the `DENSE_RANK` window function, I have to calculate rank in Python. Although, initially, I did this on the model instances returned by `all()`, I decided I should be able to add rank to the `QuerySet` returned by `annotate().order_by()`, while retaining a `QuerySet` object to work with, for example with `get()`.

```py
class TeamManager(models.manager):
    @staticmethod
    def add_ranking(qs):
        # First, populate rows and rankings lists
        # ...
        # Then, add it to the query set
        literal_selects = []
        for row_id, ranking in zip([row.id for row in rows], rankings):
            literal_selects.append('SELECT {} AS "thing_id", {} AS ranking'.format(row_id, ranking))
        extra_from = "(" + " UNION ALL ".join(literal_selects) + ")"

        return qs.extra(
            tables=[extra_from],
            select={'ranking': 'ranking'},
            where=['team.id = thing_id'])

    def ranked_list(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.annotate(
            num_games=Count('team__score_set'),
            total_points=Sum('team__score_set__points'),
            # Ideally, I would calculate ranking here
        ).order_by('-total_points')

        return TeamManager.add_ranking(qs)
```

This doesn't work because Django's ORM [adds double quotes](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9049) around the  ‘table names’ in `extra(table)`

Is there any other way to add literal values to a pre-existing `QuerySet`, or do I have to replace the call to annotate with a call to `raw()` and then work from there? That would be a pity, because I have just invested a significant chunk of time in understanding how to translate my original raw SQL query (with `GROUP BY`s and everything) into a more Djangoesque way of doing things. I would love to Django my way out of this instead of dancing to my own old SQL tune.

Comment: nope, I think you're going to have to use `raw`... a more 'out there' option would be to bake that query into a view, which could be exposed as a separate model via http://django-postgres.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html

Comment: Not an actual answer, but when I was facing similar issues calculating rankings I ended up creating another table just with the "points/scores". It also made the query much faster as we were looping through some large tables. So perhaps there is a way for you to create and use some kind of "earned points" table.

Comment: pardon me, but from my point of view looks like the sorting issue, sort by the total_points and -num_games, if there will be same number of points, team with least num_games will be first (add sort by id at the end, so you will avoid pagination issues with equal ranks & games)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add literal value with [Value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions):

```
qs = self.model.objects.annotate(
    num_games=Count('team__score_set'),
    total_points=Sum('team__score_set__points'),
    ranking=Value(42, output_field=IntegerField())
).order_by('-total_points')
```

Comment: This wasn't yet available when I asked the question, but I should have definitely accepted your answer, because these DB functions (which are no now longer new) are definitely what I was looking for, and have since started using intensively.